# How to add content-disposition header in OpenAPI 2.0 specifications

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

I am new to OpenAPI specification and currently working on a project which uses OpenAPI specification 2.0. We also use swagger-codegen to generate REST interface from this specification file.

Now, I am stuck in a scenario where I have to pass an Excel file as a output to the REST call so to do that I need to mention content-disposition in response header for this REST API in OpenAPI specification so that auto generated code also has the same thing.

Is there a way to do that so that my auto generated code automatically detects that header?

```
....
  Object res = service.exportData(body);
  return Response.ok(res).build();
....
```